# Get index of iteration in nested for-each binding knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I want to get the index of `ParentArray` in `td` tag. Below code binding `ChildArray` index. How do I do this?

```
<table class="table-container-inner">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:ParentArray">

        <tr data-bind="foreach:ChildArray">
            <td data-bind="text:$index"></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what's cellarray ?

Comment: `$index` will get the index within ChildArray. within that same foreach `$parentContext.$index()` will get the index of the Parent Array

Comment: Sorry - I have updated cellarray to ParentArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$index` will get the index within ChildArray. within that `foreach:ChildArray`, `$parentContext.$index()` will get the index of the ParentArray

```
<table class="table-container-inner">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:ParentArray">

        <tr data-bind="foreach:ChildArray">
            <td data-bind="text:$index">
              <span data-bind="text: $parentContext.$index()"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```